# react-native: package com.amazonaws does not exist while configuring aws-amplify

Tags: android, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am new to react-native. While configuring app with aws-amplify ,
I am getting following error:

**package com.amazonaws does not exist
import com.amazonaws.RNAWSCognitoPackage;**

although this package exists in place. still its not picking it up.

Can some one please help me to understand whats wrong with it?

I tried to

- delete node_modules and install again
- reinstall aws-amplify.

but still not working.

Response will be highly appreciated.